# show unassigned category

Tags: categories

I have a category which is unassigned i.e. not tied to any channel.
I want to display it, but I could not so far

I have tried...

```
 {exp:channel:categories show_empty="yes" restrict_channel="no"}
    {category_name}
  {/exp:channel:categories}
```

Show future, expired, open, etc.
dynamic="no" and show="{number}" and even with category group

Any ideas?

### EE 2.5.5

I ended up creating a dummy channel, but is not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all categories aren't being assigned to channel, Category Group is being assigned to channel. You can use GWCODE CATEGORIES (http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories) with the following code example:

```
{exp:gwcode_categories group_id="x|y|z"}
    {cat_name}
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

Comment: Yup. My mistake, I was speaking about category groups. THank you Yadav.